# pivot the rows and subtract the values in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in sql server which is something like this,

```
Name    Count1    Count2
------------------------
 AAA     10        15
 BBB     10        NULL
 CCC     NULL      NULL
 DDD     20        10
 EEE     NULL      5
```

I want to use pivot and get the difference between Count1 and Count2.

The result should be like this,

```
AAA     BBB    CCC    DDD     EEE
---------------------------------
 -5     10      0     10      -5
```

Let me know how can I do this. Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Find difference` in Pivot source query

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT name,
               Isnull(Count1, 0) - Isnull(Count2, 0) AS cnt
        FROM   tablename)a
       PIVOT (Max(cnt)
             FOR name IN ([AAA],
                          [BBB],
                          [CCC],
                          [DDD],
                          [EEE]) ) pv
```

Or Use `Conditional Aggregate`

```
SELECT Max(CASE WHEN name = 'AAA' THEN Isnull(Count1, 0) - Isnull(Count2, 0) END) [AAA],
       Max(CASE WHEN name = 'BBB' THEN Isnull(Count1, 0) - Isnull(Count2, 0) END) [BBB],
       Max(CASE WHEN name = 'CCC' THEN Isnull(Count1, 0) - Isnull(Count2, 0) END) [CCC],
       Max(CASE WHEN name = 'DDD' THEN Isnull(Count1, 0) - Isnull(Count2, 0) END) [DDD],
       Max(CASE WHEN name = 'EEE' THEN Isnull(Count1, 0) - Isnull(Count2, 0) END) [EEE]
FROM   tablename
```

Comment: I tried it but I am getting error Invalid column name 'Count1'.

Comment: @Arpita - do you have column called `Count1` in your table

Comment: Yes. I am sorry. I had modified the column and I forgot that. It's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to calculate the difference, then apply pivot to it:

```
;WITH CTE AS
 (
    SELECT Name, ISNULL(Count1, 0) - ISNULL(Count2,0) AS Diff
    FROM #T
)
SELECT [AAA], [BBB], [CCC], [DDD], [EEE]
FROM CTE
PIVOT
(
   AVG(Diff)
   FOR Name IN ([AAA], [BBB], [CCC], [DDD], [EEE])
) AS Pvt
```